# Reemplazar datos en una columna MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla **Computadoras**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero reemplazar solo la columna **departamento** por una cadena de texto.

Y estoy usando la siguiente consulta:

```
UPDATE computers SET departamento = REPLACE (departamento, (1), "Administración");
UPDATE computers SET departamento = REPLACE (departamento, (2), "Contabilidad");
```

En donde si el valor  del departamento es **1**, lo reemplaza por "**Administracion**", si es **2**, lo reemplaza por "**Contabilidad**".

Hasta ahi, todo bien.

El problema viene cuando en departamento tengo **11**, y lo reemplaza por "**AdministracionAdministracion**", o tiene **12**, y lo reemplaza por "**AdministracionContabilidad**".

Intento lo siguiente:

```
UPDATE computers SET departamento = REPLACE (departamento, (11), "Call Center 2");
UPDATE computers SET departamento = REPLACE (departamento, (12), "Call Center 3");
```

Pero no funciona :(

Comment: La primer pregunta.. seria porque?... lo segundo.. esto se soluciona mucho mejor con un join. tenes una tabla de porque hacer cada reemplazo?

Comment: Lo que quiero es reemplazar los numeros de departamento, por sus correspondientes nombres.

Comment: Bien extraño que quieras denormalizar los datos. Usualmente, lo correcto es tal como lo tienes y tener una tabla separada `departamento` al que le puedes hacer un join para obtener los nombres. De hecho me sorprende que tu columna `departamento` no sea numérico.

Comment: eso lo entendi perfectamente.. lo que te pregunte es la razon (no veo la logica en eso) y mas alla de eso pregunte si tenias una tabla codigo/departamente

Comment: Si, tengo una tabla de computadoras (es la que ven) tengo una tabla de departamentos, y tengo una tabla de computadoras/departamentos. Solo quiero modificar la columna. Se que no tiene logica, pero es para resolver un problema.

Comment: es para resolver un problema de que tipo? no deberias desnormalizar una tabla

Comment: @EVM: Sé que es un poco fastidioso cuestionar la razón de lo que pides. Pero nuestro objetivo no es solo contestar preguntas de forma ciega. Mas allá de eso, deseamos ayudar a la comunidad a tomar buenas deciciones y seguir las mejores prácticas. Y francamente, no te estaríamos haciendo un favor, ni a los demás que leen esta pregunta, si no cuestionamos un poco lo que estás tratando de hacer. Tal vez al entender mejor tu problema, podemos recomendarte una solución mucho mas adecuada de lo que tenías pensado, y que tal vez te evita cometer un error grave de diseño.

Comment: Tengo una tabla de departamentos, en la cual solo tengo 15 departamentos, el cual a su vez, solo esta relacionada con la tabla de computadoras. Quiero reemplazar la columna departamento, porque solo les desplegare a los usuarios una lista desplegable desde la misma tabla de computadoras. Todavia tengo mi tabla de departamentos, pero lo que hare, solo hacer una lista en la tabla computadoras. Tampoco quiero que se mal interprete la pregunta.

Comment: esta perfecta esa tabla!!! porque quieres romper algo totalmente valido...???

Comment: ¿Y cual es el problema que te tiene convencido que debes mover los nombres directamente en la tabla `computadoras`?

Comment: la pregunta es.. mañana.. cuando le cambien el nombre al departamento Call Center 2 por centro de llamadas.. vas a hacer un gran update a esta tabla?? o solo vas a modificar un registro en otra tabla?

Answer (score 3):

Voy a dejar la respuesta solo como referencia...

**NO SE RECOMIENDA DESNORMALIZAR UNA TABLA (salvo que sea un datawarehouse)**

**OJO** esta solucion es solo valida para MYSQL, en otros motores se escribe diferente.

Se deberia hacer algo asi:

```
UPDATE
    computadoras c
    JOIN
    departamentoscomputadoras dc ON c.departamento=dc.id_departamento 
SET
    c.departamento = dc.departamento
```

Comment: Tienes mi voto tanto por la solución como por recomendar no usarla.

Answer (score 0):

En vez de hacer un replace podrias probar con

```
UPDATE computers SET departamento = "Administración" WHERE departamento = 1;
UPDATE computers SET departamento = "Contabilidad" WHERE departamento = 2;
```

Y en el segundo caso , simplemente tendrias que reemplazar el 1 y el 2 por 11 y 12 y te funcionara perfectamente:

```
UPDATE computers SET departamento = "Call Center 1" WHERE departamento = 11;
UPDATE computers SET departamento = "Call Center 2" WHERE departamento = 12;
```

Comment: El problema de esto (y la otra respuesta) es que si los departamentos son 150, tiene que escribir 150 updates...

Comment: @gbianchi  Tienes razon , podría hacerse también con un join a la tabla que almacene dichos departamentos y recoger sus nombres, y se que sería mejor que simplemente sustituir directamente el id del departamento por el nombre, me limite a responder la pregunta tal y como el proponía en su código.

Answer (score 0):

Para lo que quieres hacer la consulta correcta es esta:

```
UPDATE computers SET departamento "Call Center 2" WHERE ID = 11;
UPDATE computers SET departamento "Call Center 3" WHERE ID = 12;
.....
```

Comment: El problema de esto (y la otra respuesta) es que si los departamentos son 150, tiene que escribir 150 updates...

Comment: En ese caso hay algunos trucos como usar Excel, de manera que pegas en una celda una parte de la query, en otra pones el departamento, luego la segunda parte de la query y en una cuarta el id y concatenas todo en una 5ª celda.

Comment: Excel es un truco valido. pero te puedo asegurar que hay mejores formas de solucionar este problema.

Comment: Por supuesto, simplemente daba una solución sencilla puesto que desconozco el nivel de sql de la persona que tenga que hacer el update ;)

Comment: Fijate en los comentarios a la pregunta. No solo se trata de responder, si no que la respuesta sea completa, y sirva a futuros usuarios, mas alla del nivel de quien pregunta. Mira [answer]. Igual te agradezco el aporte y sigue asi!!!!! (ah, y fijate que estamos comentando la pregunta sin siquiera contestarla, porque dudamos de que sea lo que realmente necesita)

Comment: Gracias a ti, lo leeré. Al final en este mundo hay mil formas de hacer las cosas, cada una distinta en base a tus recursos y conocimientos y yo intentaba dar una respuesta que sirviera a la máxima cantidad de gente posible. En cualquier caso, como se comenta en la otra respuesta un join con la tabla de departamentos es la solución ideal